# Github - Google pubsub java samples - Unable to deploy appengine-push application to appspot.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to deploy Google pubsub java samples - appengine push application by referring [Google pubsub java samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/tree/master/appengine-push).

I am deploying using,

```
mvn gcloud:deploy -Dgcloud.version=1 -DskipTests=true
```

Below is the complete output with errors. Help me to fix the errors and deploy the app.

```
E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push>mvn gcloud:deploy -Dgcloud.version=1 -DskipTests=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.9.121.v20160815 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.9.121.v20160815: Plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.9.121.v20160815 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.9.121.v20160815 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Example for the Google Cloud Pub/Sub on Google App Engine. 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.9.121.v20160815 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.9.121.v20160815: Plugin com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:2.0.9.121.v20160815 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.9.121.v20160815 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.90.v20151210:deploy (default-cli) > package @ pubsub-appengine-sample >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check (validate) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Starting audit...
Audit done.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 10 source files to E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\war\WEB-INF\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:display-dependency-updates (default) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine ... 1.21.0 -> 1.22.0
[INFO]   com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub ...
[INFO]                                        v1-rev8-1.21.0 -> v1-rev11-1.22.0
[INFO]   com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk .......... 1.9.31 -> 1.9.42
[INFO]   org.mockito:mockito-all ........................ 1.10.19 -> 2.0.2-beta
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.2:display-plugin-updates (default) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO]
[INFO] The following plugin updates are available:
[INFO]   com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin  2.0.9.90.v20151210 -> 2.0.9.121.v20160815
[INFO]   maven-checkstyle-plugin ................................ 2.15 -> 2.17
[INFO]   maven-compiler-plugin .................................. 3.3 -> 3.5.1
[INFO]   org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin .............. 3.0.3 -> 3.0.4
[INFO]   org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin .................. 2.2 -> 2.3
[INFO]
[WARNING] The following plugins do not have their version specified:
[WARNING]   maven-clean-plugin ........................ (from super-pom) 3.0.0
[WARNING]   maven-deploy-plugin ....................... (from super-pom) 2.8.2
[WARNING]   maven-install-plugin ...................... (from super-pom) 2.5.2
[WARNING]   maven-resources-plugin .................... (from super-pom) 3.0.1
[WARNING]   maven-site-plugin ......................... (from super-pom) 3.5.1
[WARNING]   maven-surefire-plugin .................... (from super-pom) 2.19.1
[INFO]
[INFO] Project defines minimum Maven version as: 3.1.0
[INFO] Plugins require minimum Maven version of: 3.1.0
[INFO] Note: the super-pom from Maven 3.3.9 defines some of the plugin
[INFO]       versions and may be influencing the plugins required minimum Maven
[INFO]       version.
[INFO]
[INFO] No plugins require a newer version of Maven than specified by the pom.
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:exploded (default) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Exploding webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [pubsub-appengine-sample] in [E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\war]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1757 msecs]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [pubsub-appengine-sample] in [E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\war]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1588 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\war.war
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.90.v20151210:deploy (default-cli) < package @ pubsub-appengine-sample <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.90.v20151210:deploy (default-cli) @ pubsub-appengine-sample ---
[INFO] Creating staging directory in: E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Running appcfg --disable_update_check -A notused -V 1 stage E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target/war E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\appengine-staging
Reading application configuration data...


Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Scanning for jsp files.
0% Compiling jsp files.
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Success.
Temporary staging for module default directory left in E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Running gcloud app deploy...
[INFO] Running python.exe -S C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\gcloud.py --quiet preview app deploy E:\java\cloud-pubsub-samples-java-master\appengine-push\target\appengine-staging/app.yaml --version=1
[INFO] Traceback (most recent call last):
[INFO]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\enum\__init__.py", line 364, in __getattr__
[INFO]     return cls._member_map_[name]
[INFO] KeyError: '_convert'
[INFO]
[INFO] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[INFO]
[INFO] Traceback (most recent call last):
[INFO]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\gcloud.py", line 65, in <module>
[ERROR] Error: gcloud app command with exit code : 1
[INFO]     main()
[INFO]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\gcloud.py", line 43, in main
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\gcloud_main.py", line 26, in <module>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     import signal
[INFO]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\signal.py", line 8, in <module>
[INFO] Total time: 30.949 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-30T07:18:55+05:30
[INFO]     _IntEnum._convert(
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/324M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\enum\__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.90.v20151210:deploy (default-cli) on project pubsub-appengine-sample: Error: gcloud app command exit code is: 1 -> [Help 1]
[INFO]     raise AttributeError(name)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] AttributeError: _convert
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: i'm also getting same error while creating maven project using m2e plugin on maven.

Comment: @sumitkanoje I couldn't fix this yet. Please post the answer if you resolve.